# How do I see the actual color of a single RGB value in Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory, rgb

Very basic question. I have a single vector (e.g., [53, 21, 110]) and I want to print the RGB color it represents in a colab notebook. Like a color swatch. What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be using the Image module from PIL. According to the documentation, you can [construct an image](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#constructing-images) with:

```
PIL.Image.new(mode, size, color=0)
```

- mode [required]:  determines the mode used for the image, it can be RGB, RGBA, HSV, etc. You can find more modes in the [docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)
- size [required]: this is a tuple (weight, height) that represents the dimensions of your image in pixels.
- color [optional]: this is the color of the image, it can receive a tuple to represent the RGB color in your case. The default color is black.

Then, to show the image within colab, you would use

```
display(img)
```

---

Given your question, the mode would need to be 'RGB' and if your vector is a list, you need to convert into a tuple to use it.

To show an 300px by 300px image, the code would look like.

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGB', (300,300), color = (53, 21, 110))
display(img)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! If I recall correctly, this is exactly what I ended up doing. Appreciate the help!